# Does the Vishishtadvaita school accept the Kaivalyopanishat? What is its status?

Tags: upanishads, vishishtadvaita

The Kaivalyopanishat reads like a Shiva-specific one with 'Uma sahayam parameshwaram ....' and also at the end specifies Sri Rudram as the means to attain to the goal. Is this acceptable to Vaishnavas in general and srivaishnavas specifically?

Comment: The Narayanastra site has a Sri Vaishnava commentary on the Kaivalya Upanishad: https://narayanastra.blogspot.in/2018/01/prelude-to-isvara-gita-iv-kaivalya.html

Comment: Is that commentary authenticated by any Purvacharyas? To be specific, are 'some' upanishads meant only for kaivalya siddhi (jivatmopasana) and not mukhya vaikunthaprapti-mukti?  Does the Srivaishnava school admit of such distinction across upanishads? Does the Sribhashyam, in its samanvaya portion, admit of 'not all upanishads teach about Brahman; some teach jivasvarupa and not Brahman'?

Comment: It's not a classification of Upanishads, but a classification of Upanishad passages.  Sri Vaishnavas believe some Upanishad passages are about the Jivatma, and some Upanishad passages are about Paramatma.  And some Upanishad passages are about neither, as discussed in Adhyaya 3 Pada 3 of the Brahma Sutras.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I did not know that.  In the link you provided, the Kaivalyopanishat is held to be solely jivatma-specific:  //upāsana ....upanishads focus solely on these topics.
One such Upanishad is the Kaivalya Upanishad. The term “Kaivalya” itself denotes aloofness from prakrti – it refers to the pure state of the liberated self that has no connection with karmas.
This Upanishad, which has “jīvātma-anubhāva” as its’ primary theme, // In this connection I chanced to find the word 'sarvatma' cited in the Sribhashyam from this Upanishad. (contd.)

Comment: Contd...https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.273797/2015.273797.Sri-Bhashyam#page/n177/mode/2up     There are several quotes by the Bhashyakara and this is one: sarvatma. This word corresponds to the Kaivalya Upanishad mantra 16: https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/kaivalya.html?lang=sa  The commentary in the Sribhashya, from the previous page, gives me the impression that Sri Ramanuja is taking that quote as denoting Paramatma. In the blog you refer, this whole mantra and the word 'sarvatma' itself is taken to denote jivatma.  Your comments are welcome. Thanks and regards.

Comment: Two things. First of all, as I said strictly speaking it's a classification of Upanishad passages, but when an Upanishad is short enough, it can be entirely on one topic.  Now as far as your Sri Bhashya link, I can't read Devanagari script, so can you tell me what part of the Sri Bhashya it's from?  Does Ramanujacharya discuss this specific Kaivalya Upanishad verse, or does he just discuss the word Sarvatma?  Because the word Sarvatma has two meanings, it can refer to the fact that Jivatmas dwell in the bodies of all beings, or to the fact that Paramatma dwells in the bodies of all beings.

Comment: Are there instances of entire Upanishads, short ones, like for Mandukya is admitted to be very short, only 12 mantras, Ishavasyam too, very short, etc. being taken as jivatma-teaching only and not Paramatma in the Srivaishnava school? The Sribhashya reference is on whether there is jiva-brahma aikya as claimed by Advaitin.  Sri Ramanujacharya is refuting this idea by citing several passages, especially the ones like dvaa suparna and establishing that all these shrutis teach jiva-para bheda only. (contd)

Comment: (contd.)  In this bunch, he is citing the shruti 'sarvatma' and  the reference in bracket is given kai.16. The shrutaprakashika too is clearly saying that the bhashya is bringing out the difference between jiva and para. The kaivalya (and Jabala ) too in the blog are wholly taken to be non-Paramatma upanishads. Hence my question. Has Sri Rangaramanuja commented on any 'small' upanishads as wholly non-paramatma teaching? If any precedents are shown that would help a lot in understanding the present case.

Comment: Can you tell me what Sutra of the Brahma Sutras Ramanujacharya is commenting on?  That would help me pinpoint the specific part of the Sri Bhashya.  And no, Ranga Ramanuja never commented on any of the Upanishads that are purely about Jivatma Upasana.  He only commented on the Mukhya Upanishads, which are all either partially or totally focused on Brahman.

Comment: I am referring to the very first sutra 1.1.1.1 athato brahma jijnaasaa.  If you want you can show anyone this page: https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.273797/2015.273797.Sri-Bhashyam#page/n177/mode/2up        That contains the citation from the Kaivalya upanishad.

Comment: If you open the link, the page in question is on the left side, numbered 159 in devanagari. The Kaivalya reference is on the third line. 'sarvaatmaa' is the word. This word is part of a full mantra: यत्परं ब्रह्म सर्वात्मा विश्वस्यायतनं महत् । सूक्ष्मात्सूक्ष्मतरं नित्यं तत्त्वमेव त्वमेव तत् ॥ १६॥  The word is the third in this mantra.

Comment: The creators of the Narayanastra blog just replied to you: http://narayanastra.blogspot.com/2018/01/prelude-to-isvara-gita-iv-kaivalya.html?showComment=1523362422575#c3883212231206769629 The editors of that Sri Bhashya book you linked to wrongly attributed the word Sarvatma as a reference to the Kaivalya Upanishad.  It's actually part of the previous quote Ramanujacharya is giving.

Comment: Thank you for the above. My response is available here:  'The Sribhashya and the Kaivalyopanishat' -  in two parts

Here are two parts on an article on the above topic:


http://www.mediafire.com/file/ktcnq3ud5ufovz0/The_Sribhashyam_and_the_Kaivalyopanishat_Part_1.pdf


http://www.mediafire.com/file/di8w7utugbxz5i4/Sribhashyam_and_Kaivalyopa.Part2.pdf

regards
subrahmanian.v

Comment: The creators of the Narayanastra blog just replied to your article; see this comment and subsequent comments: https://narayanastra.blogspot.com/2018/01/prelude-to-isvara-gita-iv-kaivalya.html?showComment=1523854623785#c21180529582652420

Comment: It's one of 108 listed in Muktika.

Comment: A Visishtadvaitin, Sri Krishnaswamy Iyengar, in his Tamil booklet 'Sankararum Vainavamum' p.10 has said that the Muktika Upanishad (which enumerates 108 Upanishads) is a concocted one by Appayya Dikshitar and his associates. So, there is no use in saying that the Kaivalya upanishad is named in the Muktika. In any case there is no pramana for an Upanishad in its entirety to be labeled as 'jiva-specific' upanishad. However, the Muktika passages are cited in Vidyaranya's Jivanmukti Viveka (14th century). The Kaivalya Upanishat is commented by Narayanashrama and Shankarananda, 13th Century.

Answer (score 1):

In Vedartha Sangraha by Acharya Ramanuja, Acharya quotes mainly from the upanishads referred in the Brahma Sutra e.g. Brih, Chan, Katha, Taittireya etc. So the upanishads referred to by Sri Bhashya and Vedartha Sangraha are of particular importance to Sri Vaishnavas.

The other Upanishads are not so much integral to the philosophy which is based on the works of Acharya Ramanuja.